# 2.18.9: gps points way off

Tags: qgis

I have just imported a few gps coordinates from a csv file and saved it as a shapefile. Moreover, I have got a vector layer with polygons in this project. Both layers are in EPSG: 32632. The first point has the coordinates 49.465550, 8.47273. If I pan over the layer containing the gps data the coordinates given in the status bar are fine. But if I pan over the the other vector layer it gives coordinates eg 457426, 5481718.

Why are the two coordinate systems different if the two layers have both the same CRS and projection?

Is this the reason why the gps points are awfully off?

Comment: I do not think the coordinate is in UTM, it looks like a lat lon one. Try loading the gps points, asign epsg 4326 to them (lat lon wgs84) and then save them as 32632

Comment: The duplicate highlighted is for ArcGIS Desktop, and even though the same concepts apply, for a more practical answer I think its QGIS equivalent should be found or an answer provided.

Comment: According to Gearth your the point 8.47273 E, 49.465550 N. lies near Mannheim, Germany. The point lies in UTM zone 32U (32N for a GIS application). So I loaded a CSV file with 8.47273, 49.465550 and for the the CRS I choose EPSG 4326.  In order to reproject the point to EPSG 32632 You have to select the point layer, right click and choose save as. In the dialog box you have to choose Esri Shape file as format, give a new name for the layer and the most important thing is in the CRS section. Clicking on the world icon allows you to chose EPSG 32632, which is UTM WGS84 32N.

Comment: To be in the safe side I calculated the X and Y coordinates using the field calculator in tha attribute table and gave me 461794.944 m E and 5479344.469 m N, which are almost the same as Gearth